# Mange divs inside a fixed positioned div, just like in google search page

Tags: css, css-position

This is my first post, so sorry for my english and the way i explain my question. I want to create a web page that has a fixed header. But the issue i having is, i cannot place a div inside the header div that appears when scroll to right. i created a JS fiddle `[http://jsfiddle.net/ruwaz/mjk4T/]`, there should be a dark blue box when scroll right, but it doesn't appear. i need just a header just like worked in signed in google search page, only change is it should fixed to the top of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

This isn't an issue with fixed divs, but rather an issue with the width of your div#header.

Instead of

```
#header { min-width: 1200px;; }
```

use

```
#header { max-width: 1200px; width: 100%;}
```

This will make the max width of the container 1200px, but will be fluid under 1200px to 100%.

---

I think there is some weird formatting going on inside of JS fiddle. I've attempted to view your page in full screen embed mode (http://jsfiddle.net/mjk4T/1/embedded/result/) And it seems to be working just fine.

The only things I did were add:

```
#username{ display:block; background-color:red; }
```

And it's working just fine.

Comment: yes it seems like weird, but the problem is not solved, it is still dosen't appear when minimize the browser window.

Comment: Adjusting to fix your answer, let me know how that works out.